# A program in javascript using constructors

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, constructor, dynamic-arrays

```
<script>

<!-- A program to search for a friend from an object -->

var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Gates",
        number: "205-555-1111",
        address:["One Microsoft Day","Redmond","WA","90852"]
    },

    steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number: "408-555-2222",
        address: ["One Infinite Loop", "Cupertino", "CA", "95014"]
    },

    wendy: {
        firstName: "Wendy",
        lastName: "Johnson",
        number: "510-555-3333",
        address: ["3555 Anyplace drive","New York", "NY","11001"]
    }

}

    alert(friends["steve"].lastName);

    alert(friends.length);

    var search = function(name)
        {
            document.write(name);
            for (var nameSearch in friends)
                {
                    alert(nameSearch.firstName);
                    if(friends[nameSearch].firstName===name)
                        {
                            return friends[nameSearch];
                        }
                }
        }

    search("Wendy");

</script>
```

Comment: Not certain what Question is?

Comment: Sooo you gave us some code and a title. What's your question? We want to help, but we need context! Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Questions MUST include a clear, concise question.  We don't guess what a pile of code might mean.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a couple things wrong with your code:

- Objects do not have a length property so the second alert for `friends.length` will not work
- When you're using `for in` you are referencing the key of the object, so in this case it will be `bill`, `steve`, or `wendy` so when you do `nameSearch.firstName` it will be undefined since nameSearch is a string
- Finally, the reason that your example is failing is because you're searching against case-sensitive text. `wendy` != `Wendy`. Also please keep in mind that triple equals checks the constructor.

To fix your code, you can try just lower-casing all of your search text:

```js
var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Gates",
        number: "205-555-1111",
        address:["One Microsoft Day","Redmond","WA","90852"]
    },

    steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number: "408-555-2222",
        address: ["One Infinite Loop", "Cupertino", "CA", "95014"]
    },

    wendy: {
        firstName: "Wendy",
        lastName: "Johnson",
        number: "510-555-3333",
        address: ["3555 Anyplace drive","New York", "NY","11001"]
    }

};

var search = function(name) {
  for (var nameSearch in friends) {
    if(friends[nameSearch].firstName.toLowerCase()===name.toLowerCase()) {
      return friends[nameSearch];
    }
  }
}

console.log(search("wendy"));
```